# Cannot read property '$elemMatch' of undefined while trying to save data in mongo db using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**I am getting the error while trying to save following data.**

**Following is the error:**

> if (fields[key].$elemMatch) {
>
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '$elemMatch' of undefined
>       at model.Query._castFields (C:\Users\hp\Documents\node-projects\musicfest1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4306:23)
>       at model.Query. (C:\Users\hp\Documents\node-projects\musicfest1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1971:23)
>       at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (C:\Users\hp\Documents\node-projects\musicfest1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
>       at process.nextTick (C:\Users\hp\Documents\node-projects\musicfest1\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33)
>        at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)*

```
var data = {
  eventid: 'eventezy01',
  eventname: event_name,
  title1: title1,
  title2: title2,
  dateVenue: dateVenue,
  date: date,
  venue: venue,
  hsTicket: hsTicket,
  ticketLink: ticketLink,
  ticketPrice: ticketPrice,
  about_heading: about_heading,
  aboutEvent1: aboutEvent1,
  singer_heading: singer_heading,
  hsSinger: hsSinger,
  sponsor_heading: sponsor_heading,
  hsSponsor: hsSponsor,
  singer: arrSinger,
  sponsors: arrSponsor,
  flocation: flocation,
  femail: femail,
  fcontact: fcontact,
  fbLink: fbLink,
  twitterLink: twitterLink,
  youTubeLink: youTubeLink,
  gPlusLink: gPlusLink,
  instaLink: instaLink,
  color: '#f50136',
  bgImage: 'slider.png',
  font: '"Montserrat", sans-serif'
};  

FestData.findOne({eventid: 'eventezy01'}, data, options, (err, doc) => {
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
}


if(!doc) {

  var festData = new FestData(data);
  festData.save();      
}
```

Comment: I think you should look at findOne method again, and also `update (upsert)` also. You are trying to save 'data' according to your subject line but you are using `findOne` with wrong signature.

Comment: i'm having var options = {upsert:true}; Should i use some other method instead of findOne()?

Comment: you should use `update`  look some examples in google `https://www.pabbly.com/tutorials/node-js-mongodb-update-into-database/`

Comment: Okay.. I'll try. Thank you so much

Comment: can you paste the model ? or may be any on save hooks are there?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you're passing in data to the second parameter of the `findOne` method, but that argument is for selecting which fields to include. If the found record doesn't have any one of those fields, it will produce this error. You should supply `null` as the second argument to `findOne` instead.

See the docs on [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)